# Error in a Maclaurin series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having trouble figuring out what I have to do with this question.

"Using Taylor's theorem, determine the largest positive real value $r$ for which we can guarantee that the Maclaurin polynomial $P_6(x)$ of $f(x)$ has an error of less than $0.2$ on the interval $0 < x< r$."

Relevant information:
$f(x) = (\sin(x))^2$

I calculated $P_6(x)$ to be $x^2 - (x^4)/3 + 2x^6/45$

I calculated the error $R_6(x) = -4\sin(2c)*x^7/315$

The little info I gather from this question (may be incorrect) and where I am stuck:

Since $c$ lies between $a$ and $x$ this means that $0 < c < x$ since $0 < x < r$.
 I know I will be solving the error equation for $r$, but I don't know what to do with the $c$ and $x$ in the equation, or what to substitute in their place.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing fine; now you want to use that $\displaystyle\lvert R_6(x)\rvert=\frac{4\lvert\sin 2c\rvert\lvert x\rvert^7}{315}<\frac{4r^7}{315}$

since $|\sin 2c|\le1$, and $|x|^7=x^7<r^7$ since $0<x<r$.

Now solve $\displaystyle\frac{4r^7}{315}<.2$ for $r$.

---

(Notice that in this case, $P_6(x)=P_7(x)$, so we could get even a better estimate using $\lvert R_7(x)\rvert$ instead.)

Answer (score 0):

i think you can simplify first, for example, 
$$\begin{align}\sin^2x &= \frac12 - \frac12\cos 2x \\
& =\frac12 - \frac12\left(1 - \frac1{2}(2x)^2 + \frac1{4!}(2x)^4  - \frac1{6!}(2x)^6 + \frac1{8!}(2x)^8 - \cdots\right)\\
&=x^2-\frac13x^4 + \frac2{45}x^6-\frac{2^7}{8!}x^8+\cdots\end{align}$$ this is an alternating series so the error committed by stopping at the third term negative and smaller than absolute value.

we can make  $$\frac{2^7}{8!}r^8 \le 0.2 \text{  by demanding }r \le \left(0.2\times 8!/2^7\right)^{1/6} = 1.99475 $$

therefore the sixth degree polynomial $$ P_6(x)= x^2-\frac13x^4 + \frac2{45}x^6$$ approximates $\sin^2 x$ within $0.2$ for $|x| \le 1.99475$

Comment: I think this way of estimating the error is simpler than using Taylor's theorem.  (I believe you are assuming that the 4th term is smaller than the 3rd term in absolute value, so that $x^2<14$.)